# Magento. Не грузятся изображения и js-файлы

Tags: php, mysql, apache, magento, openserver

После установки на локальный сервер Openserver не грузятся изображения и яваскрипты. 
Например
http://magento2.loc/pub/static/version1483645234/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/images/logo.svg
404 error: Page not found.

Magento 2.1.3
Windows 10
Openserver 5.2.6
MySQL-5.7-x64
PHP-7.0-x64
Apache-PHP-7-x64

Comment: Физически файлы существуют в нужных папках?

Comment: Нет. Если URL разобрать, то часть version1483645234 в физическом пути отсутствует, остальная цепочка папок присутствует, но самого файла logo.svg в конечной папке images нет.

Answer (score 1):

Следует выполнить `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` и проверить что работают (корректно) реврайты. Если отключен `mod_rewrite` в апаче - включить. Если не помогло, указать правильную базу в `pub/static/.htaccess`, примерно так должна выглядеть секция с реврайтами:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /pub/static
    # Remove signature of the static files that is used to overcome the browser cache
    RewriteRule ^version.+?/(.+)$ $1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* ../static.php?resource=$0 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Или отключить настройку использования версий для статики. Вот она в админке (которая скорее всего для вас недоступна изза остутсвия статики ;) ):

[image: настройка в админке использование версии для статик файлов]

Можно поменять (для дефолтного scope) следующим запросом в MySQL:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data`(`path`, `value`) 
    VALUES ('dev/static/sign',0) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = 0;
```

Затем следует выполнить команду:

```
bin/magento cache:clean config
```

чтобы очистить кеш конфигурации (если он был).

Вот [пример настройки реврайтов для apache и nginx](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150418/static-content-is-not-loading-after-upgrade-to-2-1-3) (на англ., но должно быть понятно какие настройки использовать в конфиге).